# Undeploying a Grails App from Glassfish gets a Class invariant violation

Tags: grails, glassfish, log4j

I have a Grails application that runs in Glassfish but when I undeploy it gets a

> Class invariant violation

A quick look at the stacktrace and search on the web reports that this is a problem with Log4j

I am using the latest log4j at the time `log4j-1.2.16.jar`

Any suggestions how to overcome this error.

`[Mon, 22-Aug-2011 @ 09:23:32.494] [admin-thread-pool-4848(64)] ERROR javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging  - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Class invariant violation
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLoggerRepository(LogManager.java:199)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:228)
        at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:73)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:243)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:255)`

[Edit 1]

I have just found this on the spring source forum which is interesting:

The following are recommended to avoid this problem:

1. Set the org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES system property to false.
2. Apply the patch from bug 40212 or upgrade to a version that has that patch applied.
3. Upgrade to log4j 1.2.16 or later to better defend against class loader attack or provide a better diagnostic message when it does occur.

[Solution]
Setting the property

```
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.ENABLE_CLEAR_REFERENCES = false
```

in the domain.xml file in Glassfish resolves the issue

Comment: where did you exactly put the property in domain.xml